# How to subdivide a bone already linked to a mesh?

Tags: armature

I'm a beginner in Blender but I will try to describe my problem as proper as possible:
I downloaded a blender file. It contains a mesh and a complex armature system with bone groups and many bones. I have a bone (a bone of a whole finger) and I want to modify it. The tale of this bone is linked to the hand bone. The head of it is free. If I rotate this bone in pose mode, the mesh (finger) follows the rotation. But if I subdivide the bone, only the original one will drive the mesh. If I rotate the new bone (last fingertip), it won't affect the mesh. So basically I want to make the armature more detailed. Is it possible to subdivide bones and keep the behavior of the armature at the same time? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can subdivide the bone. Then to recalculate the influence you can try this: Select the armature, shift select the object, switch to *Weight Paint* mode, select the bone you want, go into the *Weights* panel and choose *Assign Automatic from Bones*:

[image]

If it doesn't work right, you need to paint manually. Or you can assign the vertices to the correct group in the *Object Data* panel > *Vertex Groups*. You'll see that the *Assign Automatic from Bones* has created a new group for the new bone:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! I will try them!